# How to write a condition based on multiple values for a DataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on a Spark Application (using Scala) and I have a List which contains multiple values. I'd like to use this list in order to write a `where` clause for my DataFrame and select only a subset on tuples. For example, my List contains 'value1', 'value2', and 'value3'. and I would like to write something like this:

```
mydf.where($"col1" === "value1" || $"col1" === "value2" || $"col1" === "value3)
```

How can I do that programmatically cause the list contains many values?

Comment: Just FYI, the example you are giving will return NULL since $"col1" can not be simultaneously three values?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake, I meant || nor &&.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can map a list of values to a list of "filters" (with type `Column`), and reduce this list into a single filter by applying the `||` operator on every two filters:

```
val possibleValues = Seq("value1", "value2", "value3")
val result = mydf.where(possibleValues.map($"col1" === _).reduce(_ || _))
```

Comment: When run that, the inner part of the where function (possibleValues.map($"col1" === _).reduce(_ || _)) generates something like this:

((((col1= value1) || (col2 = value2))

why there are extra parenthesis in the beginning?